# How to install cross platform development tools to my existing visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cross-platform

I have installed visual studio 2015 profession with out cross platform development tool. Can i add these tools to this installation from downloading it from other computer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

**Step 1:** Download or copy the tool set up.

**Step 2:** Install the tool , It will automatically set the tools in your VS 2015, You just need to restart the studio.